# Fetch entries with special characters in title

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel

When trying to fetch an entry with special characters in the title, it doesn't seem to match.

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->title = "Title,with,commas";
$entry = $criteria->first();
```

I've also tried a few other characters such as `#`, `%`, and `$` with the same result - `$entry` is empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [`DbHelper::parseParam`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/helpers/DbHelper#parseParam-detail) docs:

> If the $value is a string, it will automatically be converted to an array, split on any commas within the string (via ArrayHelper::stringToArray()). If that is not desired behavior, you can escape the comma with a backslash before it.

To escape the comma and other characters treated as special in [`DbHelper::parseParam`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/helpers/DbHelper#parseParam-detail) use the [`DbHelper::escapeParam`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/helpers/DbHelper#escapeParam-detail) helper:

```
$criteria->title = DbHelper::escapeParam("Title, with, commas");
```

Comment: Thats perfect @carlcs, exactly what I needed - nice one!

Comment: Updating this answer for Craft 3: `use craft\helpers\Db; ... Db::escapeParam(...);`

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape your commas, or craft wil interpret that as if your searching for several titles. Notice the where clause, "contenttitle1, contenttitle2, contenttitle3".

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->title = 'Title,with,commas';
$entry = $criteria->first();

// will result in this query:
SELECT <a bunch of fields>
FROM `craft_elements` `elements`
JOIN `craft_elements_i18n` `elements_i18n` ON elements_i18n.elementId = elements.id
JOIN `craft_content` `content` ON content.elementId = elements.id
...
WHERE (((((elements_i18n.locale = :locale) AND (content.locale = :locale)) AND (elements.archived = 0)) AND ((elements.enabled = 1) AND (elements_i18n.enabled = 1) AND (entries.postDate <= '2015-05-21 09:08:27') AND ((entries.expiryDate is null) OR (entries.expiryDate > '2015-05-21 09:08:27')))) AND ((content.title=:contenttitle1) OR (content.title=:contenttitle2) OR (content.title=:contenttitle3))) AND (elements_i18n.enabled = 1)
GROUP BY `elements`.`id`
ORDER BY `lft`, `postDate` DESC LIMIT 1. Bound with :locale='en', :contenttitle1='Title', :contenttitle2='with', :contenttitle3='commas')
```

Use this

```
$criteria->title = 'Title\,with\,commas';
```

Comment: I thought this might have been the case - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why `$criteria->title` doesn't work (maybe someone can shed some light), but I did try these other two methods and they both pulled an entry with special characters like you describe above.

```
$criteria->getContent()->title = 'Some$other$message';

$criteria->search = 'Some$other$message';`
```

I guess `$criteria->getContent()->title` is more explicit and more what you need, as search would match more than just the titles.

Comment: Thanks Alec - I would use search as its likely easier, but in my case, performance really matters, and its a lot slower than searching directly by handle.